# C++ map pointer variable sorting

Tags: c++, stl

Hello I wanna know how to sort the map which Tkey variable is pointer type.
There is getName function which return char* type. so I tried to compare with strcmp. But there are some error in the return part.

```
    struct Compare_P {
    inline bool operator()(Person const& a, Person const& b) {
        return (strcmp(a.getName(), b.getName())) < 0;
    }
    };
    map<Person*, House*, Compare_P>A_List;
```

Comment: `Compare_P` needs `operator()` taking a pair of `Person*` pointers, instead of (or in addition to) one taking a pair of references. The keys in your map are of type `Person*`; you need a comparator capable of comparing those keys, not some other type even though related.

Answer (score 2):

Your `map`'s key is `Person*`, but the `Compare_P::operator()` takes `Person const&`. You can fix that by either defining

```
map<Person, House, Compare_P> A_List;
```

or by a correct `Compare_P`

```
struct Compare_P {
  bool operator()(Person const* a, Person const* b) {
    return (strcmp(a->getName(), b->getName())) < 0;
  }
```